# Chrome developer console dos not show network request's detail

Tags: google-chrome

Why does Chrome developer console dos not show network request's detail? I expect there to be (and it was) all details about network request related to the loaded page.

[image]

Comment: Remove the filter that you have set. (I can see your filter icon is red.) - Also make sure devtools are open before the request is sent.

Comment: @CherryDT the filter is set to All and the devtools are open prior to request - no result

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, because it shows `0 / 22 requests` at the bottom, indicating that there are 22 requests but the current filter blocks all of them. Please show a screenshot of the filter toolbar.

Comment: @CherryDT resetting devtools settings solved the issue